# SQL - values from one table column to another table column

Tags: mysql, sql

**I have two tables**

```
songs (id, name, artist, artist_id)    
artist (id, name)
```

What i am trying to do is take the **id** values from **artist** and put that value  into the value of **artist_id** in the **songs** table

```
The values of artist_id in songs is currently NOT NULL and has no value at the moment
```

**ARTIST** table

```
id    |     name    
1     |     name1    
2     |     name2    
etc
```

**SONGS** table

```
id   | name   | artist  | artist_id    
id1  | name1  | artist1 | NOT NULL    
id2  | name2  | artist2 | NOT NULL    
id3  | name3  | artist3 | NOT NULL    
id4  | name4  | artist4 | NOT NULL
```

I need it to be an UPDATE statement using subqueries and this is what I have. I do not have any errors.

The issue is that **artist_id** is being filled with **0's** instead of the actual corresponding value of **id** from the **artist** table.

```
UPDATE songs 
  JOIN artist 
    ON artist.id = songs.artist_id 
   SET songs.artist_id = artist.id;
```

the subquery goes through the MySQL terminal but doesn't tranfer values over, instead just gives me 0's

```
UPDATE songs
  JOIN artist 
    ON songs.artist_id = artist.id
   SET songs.artist_id = artist.id;
```

I even tried to alter it a bit and it still displays a 0 instead of the corresponding value.

Comment: Edit your question and provide the correct definition of the table `songs` because this: `table 1: songs - (id, artist_name, song)` is not the same as your sample data.

Comment: Are you confusing UPDATE with INSERT?

Comment: I am prompted to use a UPDATE subquery

Answer (score 1):

The only way to relate the 2 tables is with the artist's name:

```
UPDATE songs s
INNER JOIN artist a 
ON s.artist = a.name
SET s.artist_id = a.id;
```

If this `UPDATE` statement succeeds then you should delete the column `artist` from `songs` and keep only the column `artist_id`.